# Xcode Table View Cells won't resize height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I am trying to have a `UITableView` with different sized prototype cells.

I set the row height in my Table View to 243. The first and second cells' individual row height are set to 243 and 465, respectively. When I run my app, both cells appear at 243 height.

Here is what I have tried:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 25
}
//does not change cell height
```

And:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 25
}
//Method does not override any method from its superclass
```

How can I configure my project to successfully resize the second cell?

Comment: Swift 2.3 or 3?

Comment: Are you sure your delegate and datasource are connected from the table to the view controller?

Comment: @rmaddy I am using swift 3.

Comment: @abhishekarora Yes my table view delegate and datasource is my VC, and my VC has my custom class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The signature of the delegate method has changed in Swift 3. It needs to be:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == 1 {
        return 465.0
    } else {
        return 243.0
    }
}
```

With the wrong signature the table view doesn't know you've implemented the method so it never gets called.

Comment: Yes thank you it worked perfectly. My upvote will register once my reputation gets to 15.